# Command line errors while using cargo build

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, solana, solana-cli

I am trying to start a Solana project on Windows. When I run `cargo build` in cmd, it works fine; but for `cargo build-bpf`, I get an error:

```
BPF SDK: \\?\C:\Users\HP\.local\share\solana\install\releases\1.9.4\solana-release\bin\sdk\bpf
Can't get home directory path: environment variable not found
```

I tried installing WSL, but when I run `cargo build` or `cargo build-bpf`, I get this error:

```
error: `rustc -vV` didn't have a line for `host:`, got:
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may be using an older version of Rust that doesn't provide the host triple, so be sure that you're using the latest stable in wsl.  More information at [How can I query rustc for the host triple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63685737/how-can-i-query-rustc-for-the-host-triple)

Before going to WSL, you can also try running `cargo build-bpf` from a shell supporting Bash, such as Git Bash on Windows: https://gitforwindows.org/

Comment: yeah i had to upgrade to wsl2, and this fixed the error: `rustc -vV` didn't have a line for `host:`, got:,

Comment: Any idea how to resolve this keeping (the single) WSL at WSL1 ?